# How to iterate through a file and create new string variables by line

Tags: python, file, iteration

I read through docs, but still cannot figure out how to open a file, read each line, store that line as a new string variable (for now).

I tried:

```
file = file.open ("users.txt", r)

for user in users:
    user = users.readline ()
    ''' this is where I'd like to add something that creates user, user, until EOF '''
file.close ()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Here is an outline (if I am understanding it) in Python idiom:

your code -- commented:

```
# file = file.open ("users.txt", r) NO! just use open' and don't use 'file' for a name

# for user in users:   What is 'users'?
    # user = users.readline () # if this is a file, just do 'for user in users: ...'
    ''' this is where I'd like to add something that creates user, user, until EOF '''
# file.close ()   # not necessary if you use `with`
```

Corrected:

```
with open("users.txt", r) as users:
   for user in users:
      # if each line of the file is a 'user' this gives you one user at a time
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
file = open("myfile.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
str = ''

for i in range(len(lines)):
  str += lines[i].rstrip('\n') + ' '

print str
```

Hope that helps.